# Complete Adblock in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser-addons, software-rec, adblock

I use a Mac and I want to completely block ads on my Google Chrome browser. What I mean by *completely* is that I don't want the ads to be just hidden. I understand that Google Chrome adblock addons currently hide ads, but can't prevent them from downloading. Is there a work around to this problem?

Also, I use Firefox as my primary browser and I am on a proxy server on a Local network.

*[DMA: Additional info taken from anwer that should of been edit]*
I am having trouble running the shell script. This is the code that I have

```
#!/bin/bash
#
EASYLIST_URL="http://easylist.adblockplus.org/adblock_rick752.txt"

TEMP_FILE="/Volumes/Sites/MacDownloads/bfilter/bfilterList.tmp"
LOCAL_LIST_FILE="/Volumes/Sites/MacDownloads/bfilter/urls.local.save"
OUTPUT_FILE="/Volumes/Sites/MacDownloads/bfilter/urls.local"

WGET="/usr/local/bin/wget"
CAT="/bin/cat"
CONVERTER="/Volumes/Sites/MacDownloads/bfilter/adblock2bfilter.pl"
BFILTER="/Volumes/Sites/MacDownloads/bfilter"

${WGET} -q -O - ${EASYLIST_URL} | ${CONVERTER} >${TEMP_FILE}
if [ -s ${TEMP_FILE} ]; then
    echo "Updating BFilter URLs:"
    if [ -f ${LOCAL_LIST_FILE} ]; then
        ${CAT} ${TEMP_FILE} ${LOCAL_LIST_FILE} >${OUTPUT_FILE}
    rm ${TEMP_FILE}
    else
        mv ${TEMP_FILE} ${OUTPUT_FILE}
    fi

    chmod 640 ${OUTPUT_FILE}
    ${BFILTER} restart
    echo ""
fi
```

I get the error
Macbook:bfilter CALVIN$ ./bfilterUpdateLists.sh
./bfilterUpdateLists.sh: line 14: /Volumes/Sites/Mac: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You could probably set a hosts.txt file, pointing known ad domains - [something like this](http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/hosts.txt) would work, assuming OS X uses a standard host.txt format (which it seems to). Unlike other options this will work systemwide, and not need any additional software.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about the most popular version of AdBlock chromeadblock.com which is used by circa 2 million people, take a look at the changelog:
"New in version 2.0: Ads are blocked from downloading, instead of just being removed after the fact!"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy. That's the ONLY way at the minute to do the block. Personally I use BFilter since that's the fastest, BEST so far (tried Privoxy, AdMuncher (this really s..ks)). BFilter provides MAC binaries, hope they work for you. [Download page](http://bfilter.sourceforge.net/download.php).  [Here](http://www.convoglio.com/bfilter/) you can read a howto about using ABP filters. I have one, http://shiki.hu/stuff/merged.txt (some hungarian adservers, easyprivacy, easylist DE, easylist). You have to set this URL into the scripts ... or do the merge by hand (like I did). (IF you want, I can put up my list from my BFilter folder!)

After you've done with the setting up, you have to modify the chrome shortcut. You have to add the
 `--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080` (I use the :9999 port, you can set it in the bfilter config). So the whole shortcut will be like: `...Application\chrome.exe --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080` (Yeah I use a PC/Windows, don't burn me for that, but you can see the example from that I guess).
**Forgot. You can use it as a transparent proxy, just use the settings menu (if you have one  on MAC) or set it up in the config file. If you are stuck comment/ask.**